# SQL Server upgrade

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Can we upgrade SQL server 2014  Enterprise Core edition to SQL server 2017 Enterprise edition ?

I saw some documentation but don't see anything with regard to upgrade from enterprise core to enterprise edition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can practically.

But is it a better option ? You need to figure the answer out for current core edition used which uses core based licensing based on number of CPUs. You can read the MS doc on this because you might have say 64 logical processors available but you might not be able to use more than 32 or 40 not sure on that number. I will update answer once I am in front of my desktop.

But to wrap in short , to utilize the available CPUs you would want to upgrade to core based model but again check in current version how it's being used.